# Приоритет классов class="red green"

Tags: html, атрибуты

Интересует по какому правилу применяются классы

```
.red{color:red;}
.green{color:green;}
```

Если в элемент в аттрибут class дать

```
<div class="red green">текст</div>
```

текст будет зеленым

А если дать

```
<div class="green red">текст</div>
```

Тогда текст будет по-прежнему зеленый

Почему так?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы сами уже и ответили: в данном случае важен порядок определения классов в файле со стилями, а не в списке классов элемента.

Answer (score 3):

У каждого правила в CSS есть свой вес, который складывается из весов селекторов. Например правило через ID эелемента `#red {color:...}` будет иметь больший вес, чем через класс `.red {color:...}`. Так же учитывается кол-во селекторов в написании правила.

Например если в вашем примере написать CSS вот так, то применится красный цвет:

```
div.red { color:red; }
.green { color:green; }
```

Более подробно можно (и нужно) почитать здесь – https://habrahabr.ru/post/137588/

Если вес применяемых правил одинаковый, то приоритет отдается последнему загруженному правилу (и не только в рамках 1 файла), а не очередность написания в атрибуте `class`.